# Extracting iterative string and assigning them into columns

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

In dataset I've only one column which is untidy and Column1 has so many rows start with date again. Sample is as follows:

```
Column1
date: 28-Oct-2017
company: BB KISS
classification: Software
roundsize: 1.2
cumulative: 1.2
round: Seed
investors: Private
headquartered: Darmstadt
country: Germany
region: DACH
description: Software development for crypto currency and blockchain 
url: https://bbkiss.de/
```

To extract after ":"

```
df$extract <- sub('.*:', '', df$Column1)
```

I want to assign date, company, classification and relatively others to new columns. Like below :

```
date          company  classification  roundsize  cumulative  round ...
28-Oct-2017   BB KISS  Software        1.2        1.2         Seed  ...
```

How to do that?

Comment: Does your text actually have line breaks in it, or is that just the way formatted it for the question?

Comment: And is your column1 only 1 company or multiple? so after url, does it starts again with date?

Comment: No, column1 has lots of companies. After url it starts again with date.

Comment: Kind of late to add that information now

Comment: In fact I stated iterative string in title, anyway I updated question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with separate and spread from {tidyr} :

```
tab <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ column1, 
  "date: 28-Oct-2017",
  "company: BB KISS",
  "classification: Software",
  "roundsize: 1.2",
  "cumulative: 1.2"
)
library(tidyr)
tab %>% 
  separate(column1, into = c("A", "B"), sep = ": ") %>%
  spread(key = A, value = B)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   classification company cumulative date        roundsize
#>   <chr>          <chr>   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>    
#> 1 Software       BB KISS 1.2        28-Oct-2017 1.2
```

Comment: This will give an error if there are more companies in column1. See comments under question.

Comment: Column1 has so many rows, start with date. Is the solution convenient for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I created an example dataset with 2 (the same) companies. You can use tidyr and dplyr to get everything to work. You need to create an id to make sure the spread works.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_new <- df1 %>% 
  separate(Column1, into = c("cols", "data"), sep = ": ") %>% 
  group_by(cols) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% # create id per company
  spread(cols, data)

df_new
# A tibble: 2 x 13
     id classification company country cumulative date        description           headquartered investors region round roundsize url    
  <int> <chr>          <chr>   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>                 <chr>         <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr>  
1     1 Software       BB KISS Germany 1.2        28-Oct-2017 "Software developmen~ Darmstadt     Private   DACH   Seed  1.2       https:~
2     2 Software       BB KISS Germany 1.2        28-Oct-2017 "Software developmen~ Darmstadt     Private   DACH   Seed  1.2       https:~
```

data:

```
df1 <-  dput(df1)
structure(list(Column1 = c("date: 28-Oct-2017", "company: BB KISS", 
"classification: Software", "roundsize: 1.2", "cumulative: 1.2", 
"round: Seed", "investors: Private", "headquartered: Darmstadt", 
"country: Germany", "region: DACH", "description: Software development for crypto currency and blockchain ", 
"url: https://bbkiss.de/", "date: 28-Oct-2017", "company: BB KISS", 
"classification: Software", "roundsize: 1.2", "cumulative: 1.2", 
"round: Seed", "investors: Private", "headquartered: Darmstadt", 
"country: Germany", "region: DACH", "description: Software development for crypto currency and blockchain ", 
"url: https://bbkiss.de/")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: Why do we need to use "data"? Because I have so many companies, not only 2. Do I need to add them into a list like above? I also got this error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a character vector

Comment: I split your data into 2 columns (cols / data). thats where data comes from. If you have all your companies in a single vector called my_vector, first do `df1 <- data.frame(my_vector, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. Don't know why you get this error, even with removing data, introducing mistakes, extra columns, it keeps working.